# Python string as build parameter to Jenkins Trigger mail doesn't read the entire string. Instead cuts half of the string while reading

Tags: jenkins

> This is inside my trigger email

`SQLScripts=["Query1","Query2","Query3","Query4","Query5","Query6"]`

> What gets read in string parameter for Jenkins build is following

> This line of code executes

`echo %SQLScripts%`

> Prints

`echo ["Query1","Query2","Query3",`

> Initially I thought this could be some problem with how I wrote variable name, I tried $SQLScripts and "$SQLScripts". But problem is with reading the variable from email.
> As I have manually added value inside jenkins build configuration and echo printed the entire value.
> Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the length of the actual printed string vs the entire string? Is is a special number ?

Comment: The length of string keeps varying from build to build. Sometimes it's null or 1 word of length 9 and sometimes the length will be 30-40 if multiple project names/ query names need to be sent with the build. There is no special character as such in the string.